# Virtual Pageview setup in Google Tag Manager using Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have a one page form with next step and back buttons that are to fire a virtual page view via jQuery. I am trying to capture these button clicks as Virtual Page Views in GTM using Universal Analytics but I am having a problem. I looked in in Real-Time in GA and it is only registering the browser url.

---

**GTM UA Tag Setup:**

I set my UA Tag up and I've set the tracking ID and set the document path to the data layer variable 'vpv' (see custom html below) and it fires when the {{event}} equals SendVirtualPageView. The Macro vpv is set up with the Macro Type as Data Layer Variable

---

**Here is the UA Tag Setup**:

http://bit.ly/QNdxKo (Note: I cannot post images yet)

---

**The Firing Rule:**

http://bit.ly/1gIAJR1

---

**Here is my Custon HTML Tag:**

```
<script>
/*Next Step 1*/
$(".StandardButton:eq(0)").on("mousedown", function(){
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'SendVirtualPageView',
'vpv': '/virtual/location' 
});
});

/*Back Button 1*/
$(".BackButton:eq(0)").on("mousedown", function(){
dataLayer.push({
'event':'SendVirtualPageView',
'vpv':'/virtual/areaofinterest'
});
});


/*Next Step 2*/
$(".StandardButton:eq(1)").on("mousedown", function(){
dataLayer.push({
'event':'SendVirtualPageView',
'vpv':'/virtual/education'
});
});

/*Back Button 2*/
$(".BackButton:eq(1)").on("mousedown", function(){
dataLayer.push({
'event':'SendVirtualPageView',
'vpv':'/virtual/location'
});
});

/*Next Step 3*/
$(".StandardButton:eq(2)").on("mousedown", function(){
dataLayer.push({
'event':'SendVirtualPageView',
'vpv':'/virtual/contactinformation'
});
});

/*Back Button 3*/
$(".BackButton:eq(2)").on("mousedown", function(){
dataLayer.push({
'event':'SendVirtualPageView',
'vpv':'/virtual/education'
});
});
</script>
```

I did test in preview mode and I do see the event firing:

```
Fired on Event "SendVirtualPageView" (6)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Image of the real time content not showing the virtual page view:

http://cdn.uti.edu/screenshots/realTimeContent.png



Firing rule:
http://bit.ly/T7m6ll

I am posting these images here b/c I am a StackOverFlow Noob and not allowed to post more than 2 images in my question yet...

Comment: Can you share url? Try inspecting the dataLayer after you click the button using the console. Type `dataLayer`. Are you using a HTTP request listener like Google Analytics Debugger or HTTPFox? What are those saying?

Comment: Thank you @Blexy here it is:
http://bit.ly/1nOQCNB

Comment: This is what I was initially trying to follow:
http://www.swellpath.com/2013/09/google-analytics-virtual-pageviews-la-google-tag-manager/   -- 

Which I see you wrote :)

Comment: Also, what version is your DataLayer variable for vpv? Should be version 1

Comment: Yes, macro is set - http://bit.ly/1lkumWP

Comment: Ah! Let me switch it to version 1!!!

Comment: Set it to Version 1 and published. Still not seeing it in real-time. hmmm.

Comment: Do you actually pass the macro to the "path" field in your analytics tag ? Because the Google debugger always shows the same url for each step.

Comment: I pass {{vpv}} in the document path as seen here:
http://cdn.uti.edu/screenshots/UATag.png

Excuse me if I misunderstand.

Comment: @RogerW , are there any spaces after SendVirtualPageView rule? Also, what is your custom html tag rule? I just copied your site and tested it, and I'm seeing the virtual pageview - http://bit.ly/1nTjgdU If you're using Google Analytics Debugger, you'll see the vpv send.

Comment: Just checked and there are no spaces in the SendVirtualPageView rule. The rule on the Custom HTML Tag is "All Pages".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it's your vpv dataLayer macro:

The Data Layer Variable Name needs to be `vpv`, not `SendVirtualPageview`.

[image]

Comment: That did it! Somewhere in the midst I changed it from vpv to SendVirtualPageView. Thank you for your help!!!